# typeid() returns extra characters in g++

Tags: c++, g++, name-mangling, typeid

```
class foo
{
public:
  void say_type_name()
  {
    std::cout << typeid(this).name() << std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  foo f;;
  f.say_type_name();
}
```

Above code prints *P3foo* on my ubuntu machine with g++. I am not getting why it is printing *P3foo* instead of just *foo*. If I change the code like

```
    std::cout << typeid(*this).name() << std::endl;
```

it prints *3foo*.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Because it is a pointer to foo. And foo has 3 characters. So it becomes `P3foo`. The other one has type `foo`, so it becomes `3foo`. Note that the text is implementation dependent, and in this case GCC just gives you the internal, mangled name.

Enter that mangled name into the program `c++filt` to get the unmangled name:

```
$ c++filt -t P3foo
foo*
```

Comment: WOW! Interesting. Two more questions.. 1 - c++filt is part of gcc distribution or part of LINUX? 2 - Is there any way to get the mangled name of a method or class?

Comment: c++filt is part of binutils (the package where ld (the linker) and the other small utils like readelf also come from): http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/

Comment: there is no way to do that in C++. In GCC, however there is a function exposed by the ABI that does do this. It's in cxxabi.h and called __cxa_demangle . just pass it the mangled name. Its interface follows this ABI: http://www.codesourcery.com/public/cxx-abi/abi.html#demangler

Comment: Also remember that the result of typeid().name() is going to be implementation dependent. I do not believe that there is even a requirement that it yield something intelligible much less human readable.

Comment: visual c++, i believe, even yields a human readable string. but indeed there is no requirement for that. many things regarding type_info are unspecified (It's described in 18.5.1 in the C++ standard).

Answer (score 19):

`std::type_info::name()` returns an implementation specific name. AFAIK, there is no portable way to get a "nice" name, although GCC [has one](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html). Look at [`abi::__cxa_demangle()`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html).

```
int status;
char *realname = abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(obj).name(), 0, 0, &status);
std::cout << realname;
free(realname);
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It was a great help in my current project.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a portable solution

workaround would be to make a template hack to return all harcoded type names as `char*`

which platform dont have `#include <cxxabi.h>`?

Comment: Without special support from the class itself (like `whoami()` method) any "template hack" can only output a *static* type, not the *dynamic* one (consider a pointer to polymorphic base class).

Comment: Qt provides a very nice reflection mechanism with its metaobject system. I recommend it highly.