# About typeid function in C++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [typeid() returns extra characters in g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789402/typeid-returns-extra-characters-in-g)

I learned from  [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/typeinfo/type_info/) that ***typeid*** function can get variable's type infomation in C++. But the result is a bit strange in my machine.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
};
int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    vector<vector<int> > v2;
    Test t;
    cout<<"typeid for class Test: "<<typeid(t).name()<<endl;
    cout<<"typeid for vector<int>: "<<typeid(v).name()<<endl;
    cout<<"typeid for vector<vector<<int> >: "<<typeid(v2).name()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

After running this code, the output in my machine is:

```
typeid for class Test: 4Test
typeid for vector<int>: St6vectorIiSaIiEE
typeid for vector<vector<<int> >: St6vectorIS_IiSaIiEESaIS1_EE
```

I'm quite confused with the "4" before the class "Test" and the strange letters around the vector. Can anybody give me some explanations? Thank you!

My operating system is Fefora 17, g++ (GCC) 4.7.0 20120507 (Red Hat 4.7.0-5)

Comment: It's not portable, in case you didn't guess that already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`typeid function can get variable's type infomation in C++`

It's true, but when u call the `type_info::name()` function you get an **unique** name for each different type, but the standard does not guarantee that the name is somewhat meaningful. 
And it is also implementation-dependent.

What you get in practice (at least for most/all implementation) is the *[mangled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)* name of that type.

In short, you can use `type_info::name()` only for comparison, or for debugging (and you'll have to demangle the name by yourself to get something meaningful)

**EDIT**
Since you use gcc, you may want to check out this page: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html

Comment: The link is very useful, thank you, sbabbi.