# How can I remove the number associated with typeid( ).name( ) in C++?

Tags: c++, casting, typeid

I have a factory method class that generates "Items" and returns a pointer to the Item that it creates.

I have derived classes of Item. For example, Item can be a "weapon" "consumable" or "armor."

I need to detect which type of Item is created so that I can properly cast the Item to that type. I did some test lines and it looks like it's doing what I want, except for adding a number associated with the type.

### Example:

I had the line:

```
cout << "Type Created: " << typeid(pItem).name() << endl;
```

Which return the base class Item, but it would display: "4Item"

I then changed that to:

```
cout << "Type Created: " << typeid(*pItem).name() << endl;
```

Which would give me the correct derived type, but also throw in that number. So I get something like "5Armor"

Why did pItem return the base class? And why does it return an int with the type? How can I remove the int?

### A solution that does what I want - In a "cheating" kind of way:

```
            string type;
            string returnedType = typeid(*pItem1).name();
            for (int i=1; i < returnedType.length(); i++){
                    type.push_back(returnedType[i]);
            }
            cout << "type: " << type << endl;
```

Thanks

Comment: Your code looks like a very roundabout way of writing `string type = returnedType.substr(1);`.  Of course, it'll also fail the moment one of your classes has a length longer than 9 characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably shouldn't use type-codes and switch/downcasts for this. Instead, put your object-specific code into a virtual method or (depending on the problem at hand) use a visitor pattern. Your current approach will probably look something like this in the end:

```
int price = 0;

if (obj->get_type_str() == "armor")
{
    price = 1000 + ((Armor *)obj)->get_durability() * 100;
}
else if (obj->get_type_str() == "ninjasword")
{
    price = 5000 * ((NinjaSword *)obj)->get_damage();
}
else if (obj->get_type_str() == "bfg")
{
    price = 20000;
}

shop->show_price(price);
```

The problem is, that this isn't very extensible. Instead of defining the price of an object along with the object, it will be littered around the code. A better way would be to provide a virtual method get_price(), that can do this:

```
class GameObject
{
public:
    virtual ~GameObject() {}
    virtual int get_price() const = 0;
};

class Armor: public GameObject
{
public:
    virtual int get_price() const
    {
        return 1000 + durability * 100;
    }

private:
    int durability;
};

class NinjaSword: public GameObject
{
public:
    virtual int get_price() const
    {
        return 5000 * damage;
    }

private:
    int damage;
};

class Bfg: public GameObject
{
public:
    virtual int get_price() const
    {
        return 20000;
    }
};
```

Now your object-specific code stays in the object and the previous code example simply becomes:

```
shop->show_price(obj->get_price());
```

If the code in question doesn't really belong to the object, this may be a case for the [Visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) pattern.

Answer (score 10):

`typeid` returns a `const std::type_info&`.  The `std::type_info` type has a function called `name` that returns an implementation-defined string representation of the name of the underlying type.  There are absolutely no guarantees about what this function is going to return - it doesn't have to return a string that looks anything at all like the name of the type in the original program, and can decorate it however it would like to.

If you need to keep track of the name of the type that you created, I would suggest just adding in a virtual function like this one to your hierarchy:

```
virtual std::string getType() const = 0;
```

This function could return a nice, human-readable representation of the type that is guaranteed to behave in the way that you want (because you're responsible for writing it).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok that helps, thanks. I'm not sure how I would implement that though.

Comment: @Justin- You just need to implement this function in each class in your hierarchy, just like any other function.

Comment: could I just define a string variable that calls the typeid().name() and then strip the int from the beginning?

Comment: I added a for loop. I'll edit my question with what I did. It seems to do what I want.

Comment: @Justin, Go run it on another compiler and watch it burn. The thing is that you have no say in what is returned. Each compiler does what it wants. This solution will work, guaranteed, for every compiler.

Comment: @chris ah ok thanks. So do I just put that in the header of each class in the hierarchy?

Comment: @Justin, Yes (but only the = 0 in abstract classes), and you make it return what you want it to return.

Comment: @chris So I can define it just to return a string? Or should I put that for loop in it?

Comment: @Justin, Yes, just return the string you want it to display the type as. For example, in a class called `Animal` with the pure declaration, you could, in `Dog : Animal`, do `std::string getType() const override {return "Dog";}`

Comment: @Justin No for loop.  `class Item { public: virtual std::string GetName() const = 0; }` in the base class, then `class Armor:public Item { public: virtual std::string GetName() const { return "Armor"; } };`  The implementation of `Armor::GetName()` can be in the header file, or the cpp file. of the `Armor` class.

Answer (score 10):

I use g++ and also had this problem. Now strictly answering your question without any intention to point what's the best approach, there is another way to deal with this case.

Here is a copy/paste example for you:

Create a type of yours, like MyType.h

```
#ifndef __MYTYPE_H__
#define __MYTYPE_H__
class MyType {
};
#endif
```

and a main.cpp file, like this:

```
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

#include "MyType.h"

template <typename T> char* get_typename(T& object)
{
    return abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(object).name(), 0, 0, 0);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    MyType my_type;

    std::cout << get_typename(my_type) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This would output: MyType

I came to this solution based on an answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789402/typeid-returns-extra-characters-in-g) that took me to this [article](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to convert pointers, you don't have to create your own type identifier. Just use `dynamic_cast` to convert the pointer. If the type doesn't match you'll get a null pointer, and you can try another type. Or you can compare the `typeid` of the pointer and the `typeid` of each target type directly.

Of course, not having to do this kind of runtime type searching is even better.

Comment: I'm just trying to get this done for class lol. So instead of my solution.. could I do an if (dynamic_cast<Weapon*>(pItem1) == NULL) then try the others?