# How to make C++ construction trace class take parameter?

Tags: c++, debugging, constructor

While reading [Ruminations on C++](http://www.pearsoned.co.uk/bookshop/detail.asp?item=164927) I’ve come upon *Obj_trace* class used to track constructions of an object by simply making it part of traced object class declaration:

```cpp
class Foo {
public:
    …
    Obj_trace xxx;
}
```

It produces output like:

```
Object 1 constructed
Object 2 constructed
Object 1 destroyed
Object 3 constructed
```

This works fine with one class. Now I wonder how to make it work with more classes at the same time, producing output similar to this one:

```
Foo: Object 1 constructed
Bar: Object 1 constructed
Foo: Object 2 constructed
```

Closest solution I’ve come across is in [this post](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/bbshowpost.php?bbsubject_id=4420&page=1) by Nick Gammon, though I wonder whether there is a way to make it work without need for inheritance, and perhaps with descriptions longer than 1 char.

```cpp
class Obj_trace {
    static int count;
    int ct;

public:
    Obj_trace() : ct(++count) {
        cout << "Object " << ct << " constructed" << endl;
    }

    ~Obj_trace() {
        cout << "Object " << ct << " destroyed" << endl;
    }

    Obj_trace(const Obj_trace & ) : ct(++count) {
        cout << "Object " << ct << " copy-constructed" << endl;
    }

    Obj_trace( Obj_trace && ) : ct(++count) {
        cout << "Object " << ct << " move-constructed" << endl;
    }

    Obj_trace & operator =( const Obj_trace & ) {
        cout << "Object " << ct << " copy op =" << endl;
        return *this;
    }

    Obj_trace & operator =( Obj_trace && ) {
        cout << "Object " << ct << " move op =" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

int Obj_trace::count = 0;
```

Comment: Do you have RTTI? You could perhaps have it accept `void*` and always pass `this`, and then keep the counts in a static map of typeid to count.

Comment: @dyp: I don't know if it counts as CRTP with composition.  But it's extremely similar, just substituting a member subobject instead of base subobject.  Takes away the ability to downcast, of course, but that isn't needed here.

Comment: [__cxa_demangle](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2216993/2948889) is nice addition to the accepted answer with output like `if ( status == 0 ) cout << "~  Object\t" << setfill(' ') << setw(12) << realname << " " << ct << "\t" << " destroyed" << endl;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template<typename Outer>
class Obj_trace;
```

and use it like

```
Obj_trace<Foo> xxx;
```

That will also give you a separate count for each object type.  Inside `Obj_trace`, you can use `typeid(Outer)` to get a `type_info` with the name of the type.

Comment: This is exactly it. `cout << "typeid(Outer).name() << " " << ct << " constructed" << endl;` prints what I was looking for. Thanks :)